# PDO Not inserting value

Tags: php, mysql

In the code below, `sessionId` is not getting updated in my database:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE user SET attempts = 0, sessionId = :sid WHERE userName = :postUser");
$stmt->bindParam(':postUser', $postUser);
$stmt->bindParam(':sessionId', $sid);
$stmt->execute();
```

I'm not getting any errors. I'm not too good with SQL, so i'm unsure if this is even valid syntax.

`attempts` updates as it should. Why isn't `sessionId` getting updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your prepared statement uses `:sid`, but you're binding a parameter named `:sessionId`.

When working with PDO, I typically turn errors into Exceptions:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

... It helps me catch syntax errors, etc.